# Django populate a class model from command, working in DB but not showing on the page

Tags: python, django

So, the problem might be a bit too specific, I am not sure but I think I missed something in the way I fill my class in the commandBase.

And what I have at the moment is :
In the back office, in the sources / articles list everything is right. But in my page, articles parsed fro the .csv are not displayed.

Here is the model :

```
class Article(ModelMeta, TranslatableModel):
taints_cache = True

"""
Press article element,
"""
date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
date_realization = models.DateField(_('Realised in'),
                                     default=timezone.now)
image = FilerImageField(verbose_name=_('Featured image'), blank=True,
                             null=True,
                             on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                             related_name='image_press_article',
                             help_text=_('Set if the article will be featured'))

sources = models.ManyToManyField(ArticleSource, verbose_name=_('Source'),
                                    blank=False, null=True, related_name='sources_press_article')

regions = models.ManyToManyField(Country, verbose_name=_('Country of the article'),
                                 blank=True, null=True,
                                 related_name='regions_press_article')

global_regions = models.BooleanField('Global', default=True)

featureArticle = models.BooleanField(_('Feature'), help_text=_('Feature this article'), default=False)

sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site, verbose_name=_('Sites'), blank=True,
                                                    null=True,
                                                    help_text=_('Select sites in which show the project.'))

article_url = models.CharField(_('Article Url'), max_length=310, blank=False,
                                   help_text=_('Use to link to the original source'))

countries_displayed_in = models.ManyToManyField(
    Country,
    verbose_name=_('Countries displayed in'),
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    related_name='displayed_in_press_article',
    help_text='Select the countries in which this project will be visible.'
    'If not selected, the project will be visible in all countries otherwise it will be'
    'visible only for users that are located in the countries selected')

translations = TranslatedFields(
    title=models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=510),
    slug=models.SlugField(_('slug'), blank=False, db_index=True, max_length=300),
    description=HTMLField(_('article description if featured'), default='', blank=True,
                          configuration='HTMLFIELD_CKEDITOR_SETTINGS_CONTENT'),

    meta_description=models.TextField(verbose_name=_('article meta description'),
                                      blank=True, default=''),
    meta_keywords=models.TextField(verbose_name=_('article meta keywords'),
                                   blank=True, default=''),
    meta_title=models.CharField(verbose_name=_('article meta title'),
                                help_text=_('used in title tag and social sharing'),
                                max_length=255,
                                blank=True, default=''),
    meta={'unique_together': (('language_code', 'slug'),)}
)

objects = ProjectManager()

_metadata = {
    'title': 'get_title',
    'description': 'get_description',
    'keywords': 'get_keywords',
    'locale': None,
    'image': 'get_image_full_url',
    'published_time': 'date_created ',
    'modified_time': 'date_modified',
    # Handle the get_absolute_url in the view to have access to the request
    # and so, to the current_app namespace instance
    # 'url': 'get_absolute_url',
}

def country(self):
    return "\n".join(([p.name for p in self.regions.all()]))

def source(self):
    return "\n".join([p.name for p in self.sources.all()])

def get_title(self):
    title = self.safe_translation_getter('meta_title', any_language=True)
    if not title:
        title = self.safe_translation_getter('title', any_language=True)
    return title.strip()

def get_keywords(self):
    return self.safe_translation_getter('meta_keywords').strip().split(',')

def get_description(self):
    description = self.safe_translation_getter('meta_description', any_language=True)
    if not description:
        description = self.safe_translation_getter('description', any_language=True)
    return escape(strip_tags(description)).strip()

def get_image_full_url(self):
    if self.image:
        return self.image.url
    return ''

class Meta:
    verbose_name = _('Press article')
    verbose_name_plural = _('Press articles')
    get_latest_by = 'date_realization'

def __str__(self):
    title = self.safe_translation_getter('title', any_language=True)
    return title if title is not None else '(not translated)'

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if (self.article_url[:4] != "http") and (self.article_url[:5] != "https"):
        self.article_url = "https://" + self.article_url
    super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    main_lang = self.get_current_language()
    for lang in self.get_available_languages():
        self.set_current_language(lang)
        if not self.slug and self.title:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
    self.set_current_language(main_lang)
    self.save_translations()

def get_slug(self):
    return self.safe_translation_getter(
        'slug',
        language_code=get_language(),
        any_language=False)
```

And here is what I do in order to add my new articles, in the django command :

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
help = 'Import list of press article from .csv'

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    ArticleFile = csv.reader(open(args[0]), delimiter=',')
    global_article = ""
    _country = ""
    current_site = Site.objects.get_current()

    for row in ArticleFile:
        if row[0] != "Order":
            if row[7] == "TRUE":
                global_article = "True"
            elif row[7] == "FALSE":
                global_article = "False"

            _source = ArticleSource.objects.create(name=row[5])

            logging.info("\n\n URL: " + row[9] + "\n")
            new_article = Article(
                article_url=row[9],
                global_regions=global_article,
                title = row[8],
                date_realization=datetime.strptime(row[4] + '-' + row[3] + '-' + row[2], '%Y-%m-%d').date(),
                #sites=current_site,
            )

            new_article.save()
            new_article.sources.add(_source)
            new_article.sites.add(current_site)
            logging.info("\n\n title: " + new_article.title)
        if row[0] == "5":
            break
```

When I check the DB and compare articles from the parsing and article added from the back-office, the only difference I noticed is the language.

For the ones added by hand it's :
"en" and for the ones from the .csv it's "en-us".

So it might be the problem but I am not sure.

And even if it is, **I don't know how to "force it" to be 'en' instead of 'en-us'**.

Does anyone has a clue about it ?
**Am I doing it right ?** It's the first time I parse a csv and populate and external model with python / django.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, so the language was the problem.

I found this :

```
from django.utils.translation import activate
```

I just had to add :

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
help = 'Import list of press article from .csv'

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    activate('en')
```

To my code and now everything's displaying correctly !

By the way, I am still wondering if I am populated my class the right way.

Feel free to comment, I would love to learn !